# How many 3-tuples satisfy $x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} = 11;$ $(x_{1} ,x_{2} ,x_{3}$ are nonnegative integers?)

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I know that the total number of choosing without constraint is

$\binom{3+11−1}{11}= \binom{13}{11}= \frac{13·12}{2} =78$

Then with x1 ≥ 1, x2 ≥ 2, and x3 ≥ 3.

the textbook has the following solution

$\binom{3+5−1}{5}=\binom{7}{5}=21$ I can't figure out where is the 5 coming from?

The reason to choose 5 is because the constraint adds up to 6? so 11 -6 =5?

Comment: Are  you sure the textbook is not addressing an exercise near to the one you solved?  Because it seems to have little to do with the problem you represent.

Comment: Your solution is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the given equation: $$x_1+x_2+x_3 = 11, \;\text{ with } x_1, x_2, x_3 \;\text{ non-negative },$$  your solution is correct.

$$\binom{3+11−1}{11}= \binom{13}{11}= \frac{13!}{2!11!} = \frac{13·12}{2} =78$$

**Your final answer is correct**, (**Now corrected**: (but you failed to show that you need to divide $13\times 12$ by $2$ to obtain $78$).

---

The other solution (from the text) would be the solution to $x_1+x_2+x_3 = 5$, with $x_1, x_2, x_3$ non-negative.  In this case, there are $$\binom{3+5-1}{5} = \frac{7!}{2!5!} = \frac{7\cdot 6}{2} = 21$$

---

**Edit after another question-update:** We now are solving $$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 11, \text{ with }\; x_1\geq 0+1,\,x_2 \geq 0 + 2,\,x_3 \geq 0 + 3.$$

We can solve in the same manner by writing $(x_1+1)+ (x_2 + 2) + (x_3+3) = 11-1-2-3 = 5$.

Then we may simply ascribe $y = x_1 + 1, y_2 = x_2+2, y_3 = x_3 + 3$ to get $$y_1+y_2 +y_3 = 5$$

From here, the text's solution (addressed above) solves the number of the required solutions.

Comment: @ amWhy I added more details which I failed to include. Please let me know if my reasoning is correct there.

Comment: In that case, you can write: $x_1+1 + x_2 + 2 + x_3 + 3 = 11- 6 = 5$.  Then, the solution in the book is the correct solution.

Comment: I elaborated above in my answer's edit.

Comment: Let me know if my edit helps!

Comment: @ amWhy Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, Tmm.

Answer (score 1):

The number of nonnegative integer solutions of $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 11$ is the coefficient of $t^{11}$ in the following generating function [JDL]

$$\dfrac{1}{(1-t)^3}$$

Suppose now that we are interested in integer solutions with $x_1 \geq 1$, $x_2 \geq 2$ and $x_3 \geq 3$. We thus introduce three new *nonnegative* variables

$$z_1 : = x_1 - 1 \qquad\qquad\qquad z_2 : = x_2 - 2 \qquad\qquad\qquad z_3 : = x_2 - 3$$

The number of *admissible* integer solutions of $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 11$ is the number of *nonnegative* integer solutions of $z_1 + z_2 + z_3 = 5$, which is the coefficient of $t^5$ in the generating function.

Using [SymPy](http://www.sympy.org):

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> t = Symbol('t')
>>> f = 1 / (1-t)**3
>>> f.series(t,0,12)
1 + 3*t + 6*t**2 + 10*t**3 + 15*t**4 + 21*t**5 + 28*t**6 + 36*t**7 + 45*t**8 + 55*t**9 + 66*t**10 + 78*t**11 + O(t**12)
```

Hence, the number of *admissible* integer solutions is $21$. Note that the coefficients in the series are the [triangular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) ([A000217](http://oeis.org/A000217))

$$\binom{2}{2}, \binom{3}{2}, \binom{4}{2}, \binom{5}{2}, \dots, \binom{k+2}{2}, \dots$$

---

[JDL] Jesús A. De Loera, [The Many Aspects of Counting Lattice Points in Polytopes](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~deloera/RECENT_WORK/semesterberichte.pdf).

Comment: This post was posted long after the OP updated the question (25 minutes after edit).  You are not answering the OP's real question. It would have been wise for you to reread the question before posting.  Of course, perhaps someone will come upon this code, so it may help some future visitor.

Comment: @amWhy Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

$$(1,0,10),(2,3,6),(1,2,8),(1,3,7)$$ which satisfies above equation, if rearranged gives 24 solutions and you have even more solutions. So your text book answer is wrong and I dont see any problems in ur method.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved also using the [stars and bars method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).
The point is paying attention to variables that take value 0.
So you have 3 cases:

1) all variables $\ne 0$
This amounts to $\binom{11-1}{3-1}=45$

2) just one variable have value $0$ (and hence two others are $\ne 0$)
This amounts to $\binom{3}{1}\cdot\binom{11-1}{2-1}=30$

3) two variables are $0$ (and hence only one is non-zero
This amounts to $\binom{3}{2}\cdot 1=3$

Taking 1)+2)+3) gives **78**

as already found with the other methods.

For the second part, you just have to adjust your question to the new constraints, that is to say $x_1+x_2+x_3=8$ (can you see this?). Applying again the stars and bars method you find

$\binom{8-1}{3-1}=21$

The situation is simpler in this second part since all variables are $\ne 0$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\bracks{z^{11}}\sum_{x_{1} = 1}^{\infty}z^{x_{1}}
\sum_{x_{2} = 2}^{\infty}z^{x_{2}}\sum_{x_{3} = 3}^{\infty}z^{x_{3}} & =
\bracks{z^{11}}{z \over 1 - z}\,{z^{2} \over 1 - z}\,{z^{3} \over 1 - z} =
\bracks{z^{\color{#f00}{5}}}\pars{1 - z}^{-3}
\\[5mm] & = \bracks{z^{5}}\sum_{i = 0}^{\infty}{-3 \choose i}\pars{-z}^{i} =
-{-3 \choose 5} = {7 \choose 5} = {7 \times 6 \over 2} = \bbx{\ds{21}}
\end{align}

> Note that $\ds{\color{#f00}{5} = 11 - 1 - 2 - 3}$.